# Google Cloud Expose Kubernetes to Browser

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have the latest 1.6.4 Kubernetes installed on my GCP cluster but cannot figure out how to expose it on an IP Address. How do I make it so that I don't need shell access and instead can access kubernetes in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#command-line-proxy:

You can enable the access using `kubectl proxy`. Then it should be available in your local machine.

Another option would be accessing the Master server if you want it available in a specific IP address.